# My timer stops after one round

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, vibration

I have this code that is suppossed to make my phone vibrate constantly. but it stops after 1 vibration. Is there something wrong with my timer?

```
var timer: Timer?

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: Selector(("doaction")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)   
}
```

What did I do wrong? help? I am also using xcode with swift. and have an iphone 7 plus if that matters.

Comment: also my iphone crashes once i disconnect and try to run the app

Comment: Show the `doaction` method, please. That is what the timer repeatedly calls, after all.

Answer (score 1):

The timer does not stop vibrating after one round. The timer *never* vibrates.

What the timer does is to call the `doaction` method repeatedly. But the `doaction` method does not perform any vibration. Therefore the only vibration is the single one in `button1`.

Answer (score 0):

The vibration is only happening when you tap the button, you need the vibration to happen in your "doaction" method:

```
var timer: Timer?

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    doaction()
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: Selector(("doaction")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)   
}

func doaction() {
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
}
```